# a for loop to plot graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a dataset that looks like this

```
a    b    c    d
x    1.1  lol  xyz
x    1.4  lal  xyw
y    1.2  lel  xyz
x    1.4  lol  xyw
y    1.8  lel  xyz
```

I get my plot with `ggplot(filter(df, c=="lol"), aes(x=b)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap( ~ d) + xlab("xlab") + ylab ("ylab")`.
I am trying to plot this for every c factor with a for loop, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot_list = list()
for(uniq_c in unique(df$c)) {
  plot_list[[uniq_c]] = ggplot(filter(df, c == uniq_c), aes(x = b)) +
    geom_bar() +
    facet_wrap( ~ d) +
    xlab("xlab") + ylab ("ylab")
}

print(plot_list[["lal"]]) # print a single plot
lapply(plot_list, print)  # print all plots
```

Comment: I got. Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "for(uniq_c %in%". Am I missing a package or something?

Comment: My typo - should have used `in` not `%in%`. Fixed now.